# jQuery Match Class and ID for Sub Menu Highlight

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu

For a recent Wordpress project, I created a fixed sub-menu with categories. Now the client wants the category to be highlighted as they scroll down a page listing post excerpts. Each post is limited to one category. I got the categories to be added to the menu id and the post class.

I want to add an "active" class to the menu item if the class and id match. I am using waypoints js to add items on scroll, and found a bit of jQuery that works if the menu link and post id match. I have tried a number of ways, though I can not get the bit of code to compare the class and id:

```
// Helper functions
function getRelatedNavigation(el){
    return $('nav a[href=#'+$(el).attr('id')+']');
}

// Waypoints
$('article')
   .waypoint(function(direction) {
     getRelatedNavigation(this).toggleClass('active', direction === 'down');
   }, {
     offset: '90%'
   })
   .waypoint(function(direction) {
     getRelatedNavigation(this).toggleClass('active', direction === 'up');
   }, {
     offset: function() {  return -$(this).height() + 100; }
   });
```

Any ideas on how to update the Helper Function to compare nav id and article class or better options for Helper Function?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a number of informative SO topics about jQuery `wrapAll` for possible solutions to combining sections in the same category, I ended up focusing on a simple `toArray` with the [Waypoints.Group](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/group/) class. I am already using [waypoints js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) for some other features and I was able to hook into the `group.first()` and `group.last()` instances. The variables callback to categories identified as ids for each item in the sub-menu and use those to select `sections` with the category identified in the class.

```
function addSubNavClass(){
    var catsArray = jQuery('#sub-menu li').map(function(){ return this.id }).toArray();
    var bottomBarHeight = jQuery('#category-bar .bar').height(),
    jQuery.each(catsArray, function(index, cat) {
        var catSections = jQuery('.single-section.' + cat)
        var relatedSubNav = jQuery('#sub-menu li#' + cat)

        catSections.waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
            if (this === this.group.first()) {
                relatedSubNav.toggleClass('current-menu-item', direction === 'down');
            }
        },
            group: cat,
            offset: '70%',
        });

        catSections.waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
            if (this === this.group.last()) {
                relatedSubNav.toggleClass('current-menu-item', direction === 'up');
            }
        },
            group: cat,
            offset: function() {
                        return -jQuery(this.element).height() + bottomBarHeight + 30
                    },
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: This solution works great for my project, though I am open to any further improvements.